# Stuck in the world of cache in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working in an application for month now.
But after running this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

I am stuck with the world of laravel cache,
I can't do or test anything locally unless I always have to 
clear the cache then run optimize again and again.

sometimes it does work and other times it looks for old code which doesn't even exists. it has stopped my ability to work on and test my code.

I haven't tested my application on production server.

Comment: don't cache on local environment, it would just be waste of time. Caching is to improve speed on production

Comment: [this post](https://ckdigital.com/laravel-5-artisan-optimization-commands/) might help you to undo it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `php artisan optimize:clear` to undo it and don't run `php artisan optimize` in your local environment.

Only enable caches on your "live" environment and never locally while developing.

This will prevent any weirdness when developing and making sure you are looking at the effects of the code you just written instead of some cached code.

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding!